# GLSL: most efficient way to make 4 filtered texture lookups, at 4 different texture coordinates, of 4 different channels

Tags: glsl, textures, lookup, glsles

I wonder whether there is a more efficient way in (extended) GLSL to do the following:

```
float r_1 = texture(my_texture, uv_1).x;
float g_2 = texture(my_texture, uv_2).y;
float b_3 = texture(my_texture, uv_3).z;
float a_4 = texture(my_texture, uv_4).w;
vec4 col = vec4(r_1, g_2, b_3, a_4);
```

Note that the uv coordinate is different for each component (the 4 uv's are usually close to each other however). These are 4 texture look-ups of which each discards 3 of the returned components, which seems wasteful (and yes, there is a bottleneck around this, i.e. having a single texture() lookup has a notable difference on performance compared to 4 lookups).

I see there is

```
gvec4 textureGatherOffsets( gsampler2D sampler, vec2 P, ivec2 offsets[4], [int comp]);
```

Which is somewhat going in the right direction, but it returns unfiltered texel values and only takes constant ivec2 offsets.

I guess I'm looking for something like

```
    gvec4 TextureWithSeparateCoordinateForEachComponent(gsampler2D sampler, vec2 P[4]);
```

Is there something like this in extended GLSL (or GLSL ES)?

//Edit:
This is a feature likely every VR app could benefit from.

Comment: ... why would you need this?

Comment: Chromatic aberration

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is no texture function that does this. Nor would we expect there to be.

See, textures store the color channels for each pixel in neighboring bytes. And memory accesses are never something as small as one byte. At least, not memory accesses from main memory into the cache. That's generally done in cache lines, typically around 32-64 bytes in size. *Contiguous* bytes.

So even if you don't care about the other three channels from that pixel, for most texture formats, you're still going to have to *read* that data. So the cost is paid.

The only way to fully avoid the extra bandwidth costs is to put each channel in a *separate* texture (or separate array layer in an array texture). Of course, this requires that you generate the data in that way. So if this was from a render operation, you'd have to render to 4 separate images.

Comment: How does reading from 4 different textures differ from the using single texture? Do you mean texture caching based on UV coordinates becomes efficient if only 1 UV points a particular texture?